# Generating random numbers with identical pairs between 1 to 8?

Tags: java

Like my question, i need to generate random numbers that have identical pairs between a range. i have tried to generate random numbers and stored in an array but the numbers are repeating more than twice. i have 16 random numbers to be generated in the range. Any idea how to make it generate only identical pairs random number?

Comment: Can you post a sample of the expected output? I don't quite get the "identical pairs" part.

Comment: yes, i need a 2d array length of 4x4. with two each of 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 as card pairing.

Comment: The question's a little confusing -- if you need 8 distinct values in the range [1,8], you're not generating "random numbers" at all.  The numbers are completely determined; all you want to do is randomize their order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will do the job I think :

```
import java.util.*;

class Randoms {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> randoms = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Random randomizer = new Random();
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; ) {
      int r = randomizer.nextInt(8) + 1;
      if(!randoms.contains(r)) {
        randoms.add(r);
        ++i;
      }
    }
    List<Integer> clonedList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    clonedList.addAll(randoms);
    Collections.shuffle(clonedList);

    int[][] cards = new int[8][];
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
      cards[i] = new int[]{ randoms.get(i), clonedList.get(i) };
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
      System.out.println(cards[i][0] + " " + cards[i][1]);
    }
  }
}
```

One sample run of the above gives :

```
1 2
8 6
4 3
3 7
2 8
6 1
5 5
7 4
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks! this really help me! this is what i wanted to look for. =)

Comment: In understand the answer, but I don't quite get the question. How did you get to this conclusion Rahul?

Comment: @Oscar : Made a random guess... and it turned out to be correct. ;-)

Comment: heheh You've earned the "mind reading" badge :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30965/can-we-have-a-mind-reading-badge

Comment: @Oscar : Haha, that was hilarious... xD

Answer (score 1):

Generally, if you put the numbers you wish to generate in an array (in your case, an array of length 16 with two each of 1, 2, ..., 8), then randomly permute the array, you will get what you want.  You can randomly permute the array using code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300848/need-a-repeatable-random-array-shuffle-using-a-key).

Comment: yes, i need a 2d array length of 4x4. with two each of 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 as card pairing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this clearly shows you how to approach the problem:

```
public static List<Integer> shuffled8() {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
        list.add(i);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    return list;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> first = shuffled8();
    List<Integer> second= shuffled8();
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        System.out.println(first.get(i) + " " + second.get(i));
    }
}
```

`shuffled8` simply returns a list of numbers 1 to 8 shuffled. Since you need two of such lists, you invoke it twice, and store it in `first` and `second`. You then pair `first.get(i)` with `second.get(i)` to get the properties that you want.

To generalize this, if you need triplets, then you just add `List<Integer> third = shuffled8();`, and then `first.get(i), second.get(i), third.get(i)` is a triplet that has the properties that you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have made this way :

```
    Random random = new Random();
    List<Integer> listaCartoes = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(int i=0; i<8;)
    {
       int r = random.nextInt(8) + 1;
       if(!listaCartoes.contains(r)) 
       {
          listaCartoes.add(r);
          listaCartoes.add(r);
          ++i;
       }
    }

    Collections.shuffle(listaCartoes);
```

Hope it helps ^_^